# How to make each array value be a value of object key

Tags: javascript

When `checkArr` has more than one value like so

```
let checkArr = [7824, 7823]
```

I would like the following structure:

```
let checkArrID = {id: 7824, id: 7823}
```

How do I make each array value be the value of my `id` key in my object?

Comment: expected output is wrong.Object cannot have duplicate key. You may need array of object

Comment: Your required result is invalid. Maybe you want something like: `let checkArrID = [{id: 7824}, {id: 7823}]` or `let checkArrID = {id:[7824,7823]}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant an array for checkArrID simply

```
// let checkArrID  = [{id:7824},{id:7823}]
let checkArrID  = checkArr.map(a => {return {id:a}})
```